# Code for not selecting any data in GridView

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have one `gridview` with some button images events, my problem is, I would not like to make possible selecting any kind of information in `gridview` only appear the mouse pointer, and not selecting anything inside, the gridview is dynamic.

Comment: Question not clear. Explain it with available code.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it. Simple because you information is in the browser and even if you display some images or div over the griview still one can get it from the source of html.

Comment: With this i make that!

$(document).bind('selectstart dragstart', function (evt)
        { evt.preventDefault(); return false; });

Comment: right click on browser >click on view source>copy tr and td values of your gridview :)

Comment: You can't stop from copying data from gridview once it is on the browser it means that the data is at client side.

Comment: I know, its only for information, read only data!of course i know its possible copying the data by clicking on view source option ;)